# leaflet remove previous polyline

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet

I have a function that will recreate polyline on click event. it works but the refresh layer still got the previous polyline. only when I zoom the map the previous polyline is gone.

My code.

```
function buildHotline(response) {
    //clearMap();
    //clear_polyline();
    document.getElementById('mapid').innerHTML = "<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>";
    //document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = "<div id='mapid' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>";
    var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://openstreetmap.se/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap Sweden</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'});


    var map = new L.map('map', {
        layers: [tiles],
        scrollWheelZoom: true,
        dragging: true,
        tap: false
    });


    var hotlineLayer = L.hotline(response, {
        min: 0,
        max: 120,
        palette: {
            0.0: '#3ebcef',
            0.5: '#78b3d3',
            1.0: '#000203'
        },
        weight: 5,
        outlineColor: '#000203',
        outlineWidth: 1
    });



    //clear first
    clear_polyline();

    bounds = hotlineLayer.getBounds();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);



    hotlineLayer.addTo(map);


    function clear_polyline() {
        try {
            // statements
            setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize()}, 400);
            //alert("erase line");
            map.removeLayer( hotlineLayer );

        } catch(e) {
            // statements
            console.log(e);
        }

    }

}
```

where do I have to put the `clear_polyline` to clear it first before the new polyline is created. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the reference to `hotlineLayer` *outside* the scope of the `buildHotline()` function, so that several runs of that function can refer to the same instance of `hotlineLayer`.

Then, check if it's undefined, remove it if it isn't, and re-assign with the newly built instance.

i.e.:

```
var thing;

function refreshThing() {
    if (thing) { remove(thing); }
    thing = newThing();
}
```

See also [How to remove L.rectangle(boxes[i])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716800/how-to-remove-l-rectangleboxesi/39718861#39718861) , as the solution is pretty similar.